# Atualizar informações sem atualizar a página com CakePHP 3

Tags: php, cakephp

Como faço para atualizar algumas informações sem atualizar a página, estou trabalhando com o CakePHP 3. Ex:
Tenho 2 listas, uma com todos os itens e outra com os itens favoritos. Na primeira lista eu tenho a opção de favoritar cada item (salvo essa informação no bd). Gostaria que eu não precisasse atualizar a página para atualizar essa informação na segunda lista.
Qual a maneira correta de fazer isso?

Comment: Já tentou utilizar uma requisição AJAX?

Comment: Poderia me dar um exemplo de utilização AJAX no CakePHP 3?